# closures and useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, closures, use-state

I'm kinda struggling to understand React Hooks and closures, and i couldn't find a simple answer for my question .

this is a code snippet [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-rgb-qr41u?file=/src/index.js:0-472)

```
    function WatchCount() {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

       return (
         <div>
           {count}
           <button
             onClick={() => {
               setCount(count + 1);
               setCount(count + 1);
             }}
            >
             Increase
           </button>
        </div>
       );
   }
```

What i fail to understand , how to make the fact that i called setCount twice , adds 1 twice and display 2 with just one click

Comment: @CertainPerformance already beat me to answer, but here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-regular-and-functional-state-updates-2rtbk) demo of mine I use to illustrate this issue and resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates are batched and asynchronous. When a state setter is called, React will queue an update to the state with the new value. So, calling:

```
setCount(count + 1);
```

will tell React to, very shortly, re-render `WatchCount` with `count + 1`.

Calling `setCount(count + 1);` twice doesn't do anything because both times, you're telling React to set the same new state - eg, if `count` starts at 0, both calls will result in `setCount(1)`.

(Remember that the `count` variable is declared with a `const` - it will not get its value changed until the next render cycle, when the function gets called again)

If you wanted to add two to `count` with two separate statements for some reason, one way you could do this would be to use the *callback form*, which takes React's current value of the state as an argument:

```
setCount(count => count + 1);
setCount(count => count + 1);
```

This will result in the first `setCount` incrementing the state, and then that new state gets passed to the *second* `setCount` as the argument, so it'll get incremented again.